# Killing Java Process from C# Console App

Tags: c#, java, .net, process

I hate to post about this again but I answered my own last post thinking I fixed it (which I didn't). Basically when my c# .NET application shuts down, I want to remove the running Java process that it created. The initial problem was that I was trying to save processID to a static class member variable (which obviously didnt work). I found a Global Class example online and used that instead, however it still isn't shutting down the process.

Debugging it isn't working properly. I guess it just creates a new instance of the application rather than running the one that I built, and even setting the working directory to the "Bin" directory doesn't work. So I am just having to run my .exe from the Bin directory at the moment.

```
namespace MinecraftDaemon
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting Minecraft Daemon...");

            Arguments CommandLine = new Arguments(args);

            // Hook ProcessExit Event
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += new EventHandler(Current_ProcessExit);

            if (CommandLine["file"] != null && CommandLine["memory"] != null)
            {
                // Launch the Application (Command Line Parameters)
                LaunchMinecraft(CommandLine["file"], CommandLine["memory"]);
            }
            else
            {
                // Launch the Application (Default Parameters)
                LaunchMinecraft("minecraft_server.jar", "1024");
            }
        }

        public static void LaunchMinecraft(String file, String memoryValue)
        {
            String memParams = "-Xmx" + memoryValue + "M" + " -Xms" + memoryValue + "M ";
            String args = memParams + "-jar " + file + " nogui";
            ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("java.exe", args);
            processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

            try
            {
                using (Process minecraftProcess = Process.Start(processInfo))
                {
                    GlobalClass.ProcessID = minecraftProcess.Id;
                    Console.WriteLine("Process ID is " + GlobalClass.ProcessID);
                    minecraftProcess.WaitForExit();
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                // Log Error
            }
        }

        static void Current_ProcessExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Loop the Current Windows Processes
            foreach (Process winProcess in Process.GetProcesses())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("WinProcessID is " + winProcess.Id + " GlobalClass.ProcessID is " + GlobalClass.ProcessID);

                // If this is our Process, shut it down
                if (winProcess.Id == GlobalClass.ProcessID)
                {
                    Process.GetProcessById(GlobalClass.ProcessID).Kill();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your code get to the `WriteLine` in `Current_ProcessExit`?

Comment: Some Java applications won't exit gracefully (if there are non-daemon threads running that refuse to stop), so that might be one reason why it doesn't work.

Comment: @biziclop: Can you provide references for that statement, please?  I'm curious.:)

Comment: @casblanca: Im not sure, it closes too fast for me to see. As far as Java applications not exiting gracefully, I guess that might be the problem. Any possible solutions to that problem?

Comment: Correction, I just ran my .exe from cmd.exe and then closed it with ctrl+c and it did not hit the Console.WriteLine().

Comment: @David What do you mean by references? Create a java application that runs a thread that swallows `InterruptedException` and you can see it for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by switching from catching the Event AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit to using SetConsoleCtrlHandler();